# Javascript - detect or override all onkeyup and onkeydown handlers

Tags: javascript

In javascript, is there a way to detect or override (to 'null') all onkeyup and onkeydown handlers applied to DOM elements, rather than iterate the entire dom?

(I this scenario, I'm looking to override onkey handlers that extensions may have inserted onto the DOM, e.g. by browser extensions, rather than detect handlers added by the site directly).

Comment: The `useCapture` flag of `addEventListener` is relevant. If you really want to know how you could make it work and why, [read about it on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: Thanks, but i'm looking to discover all existing listeners rather than add one

Comment: Read it. It'll tell you about the execution order etc. Read it twice.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use jQuery, I think this code could help you

```
$( document ).off('keypress').on('keypress', 'SELECTOR', function(e){
  // your code
});
```

Comment: Tried that - it doesn't override an event attached to a dom element, e.g. <INPUT>; 
edit for clarification - i don't know where, or if, an event has been hooked